# What does it want?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

So, I found this image. I feel like it wants something

You might wanna go ahead and download the image, because it will be useful to be able to scribble around on the image for counting and stuff. It won't mind

[image]

What does this image want?

Hint

> b is for [image]

plus one more hint

> Where does it say the dots are going to be binary?

P.S. The puzzle is all in the image. It knows to tell you on its own.
P.P.S Actually it will refer you, but what I mean is the puzzle is not in this text

Comment: -1, circle does not appear to be freehand.

Comment: give some credit for the freehand key at least

Answer (score 4):

Extremely Partial(Mostly Data Collection to help others take it further and for OP to validate if there are no errors in the puzzle)

> So, the circle has exactly 92 dots around
>
>  [image]
>
>  **Assigning**
>  Blue $\rightarrow$ 11
>  Red $\rightarrow$  00
>
>  **Dividing them in 8-bits**
>
>  11000011 11000000 00000000 00110011 11110011 00110011 00110011 00110011 00110011 00110011 00110011 11000011 00110011 00110011 00110011 00110011 00110011 00110011 11110000 00110011 00110000 00001100 00000011
>
>
>  **Converting to ASCII gives gibberish, so here are the decimal values**
>
>  195 192 0 51 243 51 51 51 51 51 195 51 51 51 51 51 240 51 12 3
>
>
>  **Central part**
>  The right side equation(I promise I googled) gives -1. Hence the equation should look like -
>
>  $b = -1$
>
>  Now, this may mean, reduce the decimals obtained from Binary by 1 or may be remove a bit from the binary. I'm not sure how to interpret it for now.
>
>  Complicated math is an alien language for me. So, I will leave the central part for others to identify and use. :-)

Comment: I like how you say 'exactly 92'.

Comment: should there be a community wiki? should this be it? I don't know how it works on puzzling so...

Comment: @DestructibleLemon A community wiki is when a question is solved by a number of users working together. Well, for now, this is just another partial answer.